# Django custom ModelField - getting a "attribute name must be string" error

Tags: python, django

So I created a custom ModelField extending CharField to have better empty string validation and to allow me to run custom business logic validation and cleaning on it. The code is below:

```
 class CustomTextField(models.CharField):
 10     def __init__(self, *args, rule="TextRule", **kwargs):
 11         self.rule = rule
 12         super().__init__(args, kwargs)
 13
 14     def deconstruct(self):
 15         name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
 16         # Only include kwarg if it's not the default
 17         if self.rule != "TextRule":
 18             kwargs['rule'] = self.rule
 19         return name, path, args, kwargs
 20
 21     def validate(self, value, model_instance):
 22         super().validate(value, model_instance)
 23         # skip special cases here
 24         if self.blank and self.rule == TextRule:
 25             return
 26         rule_module = __import__("webapp.rules", fromlist=['blah'])
 27         class_ = getattr(rule_module, self.rule)
 28         rule = class_(value)
 29         result = rule.validate()
 30         if result != "":
 31             raise ValidationError(result)
 32
 33     def clean(self, value, model_instance):
 34         value = super().clean(value, model_instance)
 35         rule_module = __import__("webapp.rules", fromlist=['blah'])
 36         class_ = getattr(rule_module, self.rule)
 37         rule = class_(value)
 38         return rule.clean()
```

So the idea is, it's basically a CharField that runs my TextRule object by default, but can be overriden to run other text type rules (e.g. Phone number, email, etc), to do custom validation and cleaning of data.

But whenever I assign this Field to a Model attribute, overriding the rule:

```
zip_code = CustomTextField(rule="ZipCodeRule", max_length=5)
```

the django server keeps giving me this message:

```
 File "/home/blah/python37env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 156, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/home/blah/python37env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/blah/python37env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 743, in contribute_to_class
    if not getattr(cls, self.attname, None):
 TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Same thing happens when I try to run makemigrations. Totally stumped now because the django source code referenced in the error is not easily understood.

Comment: At the very least, your super call is wrong: it should be `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` (with the asterisks).

Comment: Thank you so much, @Daniel Roseman, that fixed this issue. :) Aside from being new to Django, I am also a bit new to Python's more advanced features such as unpacking.